# Select Field into Message Box Sencha Touch 2.x (focus error)

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, sencha-touch

Using this:

```
Ext.Msg.prompt(
    'Test',
    'Open the picker',
    function(buttonId, value) {},
    Ext.Msg, //scope
    false, //multiline
    0, // default
    { // prompt config
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        displayField: 'value',
        store: 'SettingsTag',
        usePicker:false
    }
);
```

It shows the Msg box with the Select field, but when I touch it shows the options panel behind the message box and I can't select it unless I close the Msg box...

Like the Msg box has the focus and the options don't...

Run:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2s5

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They told me that is not a bug, because prompt waits a textfield or a textareafield.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?280243-SelectField-inside-MessageBox-prompt-Focus-error&p=1024681#post1024681

I resolved doing my own panel:

```
popup = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                    floating: true,
                    modal: true,
                    centered: true,

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'toolbar',
                            title: 'Custom Search',
                            docked: 'top'
                        },
                        Ext.create('Ext.field.Select', {
                            label: 'Test',
                            name: 'Test 2',
                            options: [
                                {text: 'aesd', value: '1'},
                                {text: 'aesd', value: '1'},
                            ]
                        })
                    ]
                });

Ext.Viewport.add(this.popup);
this.popup.show();
```